# System.TypeLoadException occured in xamarin.forms basic local database application

Tags: xamarin.forms, typeloadexception

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 01000016
>   from typeref (expected class
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Diagnostics.VisualDiagnostics' in assembly
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null')'

This is the issue I faced
I need a fix on this

I referred this link
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases)

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more Specific are you having this issue when trying to connect or do any Crud on the application?

Could you try removing all bin and obj folders then letting me know if it persists maybe with some more details about the problem where is this occurring Maybe show some code?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same problem here. Ours is long standing code and we've updated Forms and Prism to the latest version and rebuilt. I've just now regressed to prism 7.2.0.1367 with no effect. We get this error in Forms 4.3.0.991221 but not in 4.3.0.908675 (now the same version of Prism). There have been no code changes, just package updates.

It fails on the InitializeComponent() in the following.

```
   public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

I know it's not an answer, but I have now regressed to Forms 4.3.0.908675 and rebuilt and can confirm that the crash goes away.